# How to get body text from NodeJS' https?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

How can I get the text that `curl` outputs when using `https` in NodeJS?

```
$ curl --max-redirs 0 encrypted.google.com

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

The below gives me [this stack trace](https://pastebin.com/dHtt63Jn), but I don't see `statusText` or anything related that could contain the text that `curl` outputs. `res.statusCode` works, but not `res.statusText`. I don't even see `res.response`...

```
const https = require('https')

const options = {
  hostname: 'encrypted.google.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
};
options.agent = new https.Agent(options);

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(res)
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});

req.end();
```

Comment: You need to setup a [`data` event listener](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) in the `request` callback

Comment: Where is that curl outputting any status text? That looks very much like a regular HTTP body.

Comment: Use `res.statusMessage`

Comment: @PatrickEvans That was the solution. If you post that then I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update: capture response body as well.**

You can use [`res.statusMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_statusmessage) to get the status text and [`res.statusCode`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_statuscode) to get the status code. And, you can capture response body listening to the `data` event.

Here you go:

```
const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('Status code:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('Status text:', res.statusMessage);

  let body = '';

  res.on('data', (data) => {
    body += data.toString();
  });

  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Response body:');
    console.log(body);
  });
});
```

**Output:**

```
Status code: 301
Status text: Moved Permanently
Response body:
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Check the official docs for the response object here https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse